# React native : How to print variable value in ToastAndroid

Tags: android, react-native, reactive-programming, android-toast

I am working on a react-native project. I have implement list view in one of my component.

```
render() {
return (
  <ListView
    dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow = {this._renderRow.bind(this)}
    renderHeader = {() => <View style={{height: 10, backgroundColor:     '#f5f5f5'}} />}
    onEndReached = {() => console.log('')}
    renderSeparator = {(sectionID, rowID) =>
      <View
        style={styles.style_separator}
        key={`${sectionID} - ${rowID}`}
      />}
  />
);
}

_renderRow(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
console.log('render row ...');
return (
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressRow.bind(this.rowID, rowData)}>
    <View style={styles.style_row_view}>
      <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.row}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.isSelect ? 'true' : 'false'}                   </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

_onPressRow(rowID, rowData) {

ToastAndroid.show('here is your row id... ', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
}
```

Now, in `onPressRow` function, i want to print `row ID`. I have tried like,

```
ToastAndroid.show('here is your row id...(rowID) ', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
```

`ToastAndroid.show('here is your row id...{rowID} ', ToastAndroid.SHORT)`;

But didn't get success.

Any help is most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing values in wrong way, first argument must be `this` when working with `onPress`

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressRow.bind(this, rowID, rowData)}>
```

And to concate it in `ToastAndroid`

```
ToastAndroid.show('here is your row id : ' + rowID, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
```

Comment: it prints "undefined".